# Wordpress 6 - Retrieve Plugin setting inside a Block Editor

Tags: wordpress, plugins, settings, block, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am developing a wordpress plugin, in which I need to store an API key in the settings page of the plugin itself and then use the api key to perform request inside a block editor.

In the PHP file I successfully registered the setting using: 
`register_setting( 'my-plugin', 'api_key_setting' );`

I know it's properly saved because when a I refresh the settings page, I see the last value I inserted.

But now I don't know how to retrieve 'api_key_setting' value inside my edit.js file.

I've tried by retrieving the data with 
`const imaige_DALLE_API_key = wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecord('options', 'my-plugin').api_key_setting;`

but it seems not to be working.

Help appreciated